# Can't read or count messages on GSM Modem

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem

I am using a Huawei E303 modem and I am not seeing new messages via AT commands. Huawei's application "Mobile Partner" is able to read these messages but I don't understand how.

I have set `AT+CMGF=1` and when I try `AT+CPMS?` I get `+CPMS:"SM",0,30,"SM",0,30,"SM",0,30`

When a new message arrives I get a `+CTMI: "SM", 0` every single time. That value never increments. `AT+CMGL="ALL"` returns response `OK` but no messages.

**I am now out of ideas. How can I read a message if counting them always returns zero?**

What is amazing is that the Huawei application can read incoming messages, can send messages without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried to read messages in PDU mode? Even if you do will not easily be able to read the content, it might be that reading in PDU mode works while text mode not. Maybe not very likely, but very simple to test and eliminate.

Comment: Same thing happens in PDU mode. I am trying out a different solution which has given me positive results so far. I have put the modem back into HiLink mode (instead of ports mode) and when I make an HttpRequest to http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list , with `<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex> <ReadCount>20</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType>  <SortType>2</SortType>  <Ascending>0</Ascending> <UnreadPreferred>0</UnreadPreferred></request>` as a POST parameter I get back the whole list of SMS messages in the inbox. I can provide C# code if anyone needs it